# Is there any easy approach to compare two pdf or html or xml files and save the differences for the purpose of automation testing?

Tags: java, python, html, xml, pdf

XML files are very huge and if I use Jaxb for comparision I have to create 50 to 60 Pojo classes.

Is there any easiest way to compare two PDF/HTML/XML files using Java/Python or any language/ open source tool?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could compare every line of the documents and write the different ones into a new file.

```
doc1 = []
doc2 = []

with open("test.txt", "r") as fobj:
    for line in fobj.readlines():
        doc1.append(line.strip())

with open("test2.txt", "r") as fobj:
        for line in fobj.readlines():
            doc2.append(line.strip())

fobj = open("test3.txt")
for i in range(0, max(len(doc1-1, len(doc2-1)))):
    if doc1[i] != doc2[i]:
        fobj.write(doc1[i] + "\n")
fobj.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a website dedicated to this very purpose. Though this will only let you see the differences. You can build something on top of this or use this in your automation script.

[check this site: Draftable](https://draftable.com/compare)